# Representation of a non abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I know that if G is an abelian group then it has only 1 dimensional irreducible representation. Whereas if G is non abelian do we have 1 dimensional irreducible representation of G? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group $G$ has at least one $1$-dimensional representation, namely the trivial representation, defined by $g(v) = v$ for all $v \in V$ and $g \in G$, where $V$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space over the coefficient field.

More generally, assuming that we talk about algebraic representations (rather than representations with extra structures, e.g. continuous, smooth, etc.), there is a bijection between $1$-dimensional representations of $G$ over $k$ and group homomorphisms from $G^{ab}$ to $k^\times$, where $G^{ab} = G / D(G)$ is the abelianization of $G$.

Comment: Thanku so much. I actually missed the word nontrivial in question. This trivial one I know.